# Require path in nodejs frappe

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, frappe

[image]So I am experimenting with nodejs, and have chosen frappe as a skeleton for learning (as I already use coffeescript on the frontend blah blah blah). Anyway I am just getting started and have encountered a problem, so noobish, I can't find an answer on google. The picture above should say it all.

What is wrong with my path to /config/globals ? I have tried:

```
  ./config/globals
  /config/globals
  globals
```

To no avail. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

path should be `./globals` since you require a file from the same directory.

`../config/globals` would also work.

A require value with no path information looks for a module loaded by npm either locally inside node_modules, or in the global npm location.

Comment: That did infact work. I will accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.